# How to update __str__ and slug everytime after Django's model update?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created this model in Django which also saves date and slug. But even if I am making these changes again the **str** and the slug still remains the same and not updating as per the new data. How to fix this ?

```
class EntranceExamination(models.Model):
    course = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=year_choices(),default=current_year(), validators=[MinValueValidator(1984), max_value_current_year])
    month = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=month_choices(),validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(12)])
    day = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(31)])
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False,max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['month']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.course}'s exam on {self.slug}"
    
    def save(self):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = f'{self.day}-{self.month}-{self.year}'

        super(EntranceExamination, self).save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__str__` is evaluated when you can `str(…)` on the object, so when data on the model changes, then `__str__` will return something different.

As for slug, you can each time update the slug when you save the model:

```
class EntranceExamination(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = f'{self.day}-{self.month}-{self.year}'
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will however *not* work when you update in bulk through the ORM, since ORM calls often circumvent the `.save(…)` method and triggers.

It is however **not** a good idea. Slugs are used for URI's, and as the *W3 consortium says*: ["*Cool URIs don't change*" [w3.org]](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI):

> When you change a URI on your server, you can never completely tell
> who will have links to the old URI. They might have made links from
> regular web pages. They might have bookmarked your page. They might
> have scrawled the URI in the margin of a letter to a friend.
>
> When someone follows a link and it breaks, they generally lose
> confidence in the owner of the server. They also are frustrated -
> emotionally and practically from accomplishing their goal.
>
> Enough people complain all the time about dangling links that I hope
> the damage is obvious. I hope it also obvious that the reputation
> damage is to the maintainer of the server whose document vanished.